# understanding bases and frames for Gabor transform

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing, orthonormal

For the 2D discrete Gabor transform, why is it that we cannot use a set of orthonormal basis for its representation, instead we have to use frames for representing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is effectively because of the [Balian-Low theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balian%E2%80%93Low_theorem). If we were to force the basis to be orthonormal, we would end up with variances that diverge which is not so desirable (because it means our functions are decaying rather slowly).